# Argument type 'Spot.Restriction.Type' does not conform to expected type '_FormatSpecifiable'

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, enums, package.json

I've tried finding the answer for hours and haven't found an answer close enough to my situation to be able to translate it over. I am trying to create a program to pull an array out of a .json file and read it so that I can filter the answers. Thanks for any insight or help you can give me.`

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct Spot{

    enum Restriction: String {
        case breakfast, lunch, dinner
    }
    let restrictions: Set<Restriction>
}

extension Spot {
    init?(json: [String: Any]) {
        guard let restrictionsJSON = json["menu"] as? [String]
        else {
            return nil
        }

        var restrictions: Set<Restriction> = []
        for string in restrictionsJSON {
            guard let restriction = Restriction(rawValue: string) else {
                return nil
            }

            restrictions.insert(restriction)
        }

        self.restrictions = restrictions
    }
}

struct Filters: View {

    let filtersort = Spot.Restriction.self
    @State var showGreeting = false

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Toggle(isOn: $showGreeting){
                Text("Show Welcome Message")
            }.padding()

            if showGreeting {
                Text("\(filtersort)")

            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

Here's my updated code with the same error message as before.

```
    import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct Spot: Decodable{

    var restrictions: [String: String]

    enum Restriction: String, CodingKey {
        case timeofyear
    }
}

extension Spot {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Restriction.self)
        _ = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .timeofyear)
    }
}

struct Filters: View {

    let filtersort = Spot.Restriction.timeofyear
    @State var showGreeting = false

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Toggle(isOn: $showGreeting){
                Text("Show Welcome Message")
            }.padding()

            if showGreeting {
                Text("\(filtersort)") //Argument type 'Spot.Restriction' does not conform to expected type '_FormatSpecifiable'

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should explore [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types). Working with `[String: Any]` is antiquated now.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I rewrote my code, but I still have the same error. Any idea why that error is still there?

Comment: `Spot.Restriction.self` is quite different than `Spot.Restriction.timeofyear`. I can't tell what you really want.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 11.4 provides the fix-it you need.

```swift
Text(filtersort.rawValue)
```